# Python 3 IO BufferedReader Stream Internet Explorer 11 Bug

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask, stream, bufferedreader

I'm experiencing an issue on IE 11 when attempting to read an uploaded file using the Python IO library in a Flask application, specifically IO.BufferedReader. The user selects a .xlsx file, selects upload, and the file is then read using flask requests and io.BufferedReader before being processed in Pandas by another function. Edge, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox browsers work fine. The issue is only present in Internet Explorer.

The Python code in Flask is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import io

@application.route('/optimize_xlsx', methods=['POST'])
def my_function():
    input_sheet = io.BufferedReader(request.files['sheet'].stream)
    sheets = pd.read_excel(input_sheet, sheetname=None)
    ...
```

and Heroku logs:

```
2017-04-14T04:20:45.991685+00:00 app[web.1]: <FileStorage: 'Round 1 for OptiEd_cleaned copy.xlsx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')>
2017-04-14T04:20:45.991701+00:00 app[web.1]: <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f524d4b56d0>
2017-04-14T04:20:45.991718+00:00 app[web.1]: <_io.BufferedReader>
2017-04-14T04:20:45.991731+00:00 app[web.1]: <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f524d4b1af0>
2017-04-14T04:20:45.991757+00:00 app[web.1]: <_io.BufferedReader> 
2017-04-14T04:20:46.000183+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed at step 1
2017-04-14T04:20:46.000188+00:00 app[web.1]: exception 1
```

I believe the issue to be related to how Flask processes the stream in Internet Explorer, but just in case it is somehow related to my HTML markup, I've included that here:

```
<form action="/optimize_xlsx" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <div style="margin: 24px 0">
        <input type="file" name="sheet">
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 24px 0">
        <input class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" type="submit" name="submit" id="" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton">
    </div>
</form>
```

I've attempted to use io.open or io.BytesIO to read the stream but I don't believe this is the right approach. Any ideas? Would appreciate any advice or help, thanks.